# Why do both init functions get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I have a class that is setup like this to customize a UIView.

@interface myView : UIView

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        [self foo];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self foo];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void) foo{
   //Build UIView here 
}
```

How come foo is called twice whether I use

```
myView *aView = [[myView alloc]init]];
```

or

```
myView *aView = [[myView alloc]initWithFram:aFrame];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UIView init` calls `UIView initWithFrame:`. Since you override both, calling your `init` method results in your `initWithFrame:` method being called:

In other words: your `init` calls `UIView init`. `UIView init` calls `initWithFrame:`. Since you override `initWithFrame:`, your `initWithFrame:` is called which in turn calls `UIView initWithFrame:`.

The solution, since your `initWithFrame:` will always be called, is to remove the call to `foo` from your `init` method.

Comment: It is better to implement `initWithFrame:` instead of `init`. I think `init` call `[self initWithFrame:CGRectZero]`.

Comment: @rmaddy, it's the other way around. `-[UIView init]` will call `-[UIView initWithFrame:]`, which is the designated initializer. The OP would want to keep the call to `[myView foo]` in `initWithFrame:` and remove it from `init`. Possibly remove `[myView init]` all together.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer and xlc. I did have it backwards. I updated the answer.

Comment: I have chosen this as the answer. Though, your explanation could be more straightforward. Thanks for keeping up with the comments and correcting the answer.