# Why UIView calls both init and initWithFrame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I noticed that when I override both `init` and `initWithFrame:` in `UIView` subclasses, both methods are called. Even though only one is call explicitly in my code:

**TestViewController.m:**

```
@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    View1 *view1 = [[View1 alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
}

@end
```

**View1.m:**

```
@implementation View1

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        NSLog(@"initWithFrame");
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        NSLog(@"init");
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Console looks like this:

> 2013-10-17 12:33:46.209 test1[8422:60b] initWithFrame
>
> 2013-10-17 12:33:46.211 test1[8422:60b] init

Why is initWithFrame called before init?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do both init functions get called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838928/why-do-both-init-functions-get-called) anso check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW3

Comment: yeah, I also don't get the idea: I understand the concept of designated initialization as it stands: Apple's official documentation but WTF When I call **init** that calls **initWithFrame** and than again **init** in the same class while **init method was overridden** (as it stated in Sergey's example)? Such scenario must work when we don't override the **init**.  In the Sergey's example the only solution to avoid calling init method twice is to _return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];_ in the **init** method's body

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that inside `View1 initWithFrame:` you call `[super initWithFrame:]`.
`UIView initWithFrame`: calls `[self init]`.

When you call a method inside a class, the method on the very subclass is called.
So, when you call an instance method (e.g. init) on UIView it tries to call the init method on View1 (if it is implemented).

EDIT according to answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19423494/956811

Let the view1 be an instance of View1.
The call hierarchy is:

```
   - [view1(View1) init] 

      - [view1(UIView) init] (called by [super init] inside View1)

        - [view1(View1) initWithFrame:CGRectZero] (called inside [view(UIView) init] )

           - [view1(UIView) initWithFrame:CGRectZero] (called by [super initWithFrame] inside View1) 
              - ...

           - NSLog(@"initWithFrame"); (prints "test1[8422:60b] initWithFrame")

      - NSLog(@"init"); (called inside [view1(View1) init] ; prints "test1[8422:60b] init")
```

Check inheritance in OOP.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Inheritance

Comment: OP is asking why initWithFrame is called first, when they explicitly called init. This doesn't answer that

Comment: @Jeff I edited my answer, now the answer should fit the question :)

Comment: maybe my english isn't good but you said at the very beginning of your answer that intiWithFrame calls init. It's the contrary.

Comment: For clean implementation need to have one designated initializer. For UIView it's -initWithFrame: method, then better to change -init to something like this:
`- (instancetype)init {return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];}`

Answer (score 8):

It's not an issue. In the case of **UIView** a `[super init]` calling will be automatically change to `[super initWithFrame:CGRectZero]`  . So you have to maintain this code by keeping this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the small description of both method which will clearly define why init will called after initWithFrame:-

What initWithFrame method do?

```
Initializes and returns a newly allocated NSView object with a specified 
frame rectangle. This method returns the initialize and allocated object. Once it 
returned the below init method will called automatically.
```

What init method do?

```
 Implemented by subclasses to initialize a new object (the receiver) immediately after 
 memory for it has been allocated.So this init method will called only when memory has 
 been allocated to the object by initwithFrame.
```

Comment: OP is asking why initWithFrame is called first, when they explicitly called init. This doesn't answer that