# iOS: UIView subclass init will call [super init] then call methods in super class, why it will call [subclass initWithFrame:xx]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, super

I am confused with [UIView init] and [UIView initWithFrame:xx], after i search the stackoverflow and i found below questions and  answers：

[Why do both init functions get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838928/why-do-both-init-functions-get-called)

[iOS: UIView subclass init or initWithFrame:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126726/ios-uiview-subclass-init-or-initwithframe)
then i konw the initwithFrame is the designed initializer, what make me confused with the answer is when we call [myview init](myView is subclass of UIView and overwrite init and initwithfrme:), it will call call [super init] then it will call [super initWithFrame:xx] as super will find methods in super class, why it will call [myView initWithFrame:xx]???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `initWithFrame:` is the designated initializer, apple's implementation of `init` (which you call when you call `[super init]`) internally calls the `initWithFrame:` function and passes in `CGRectZero`. That is the reason both get called. So the end flow ends up looking like this:

```
[YourClass init] -> [super init] -> [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero] -> 
[YourClass initWithFrame:CGRectZero] -> [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero]
```

This is assuming you call `[super init]` when you override init in YourClass and `[super initWithFrame:]` when you override `initWithFrame`.

Comment: thanks for the help. i can see it .what make me confused is i found in other questions as i list, the answer is [YourClass init] -> [super init] -> [YourClass initWithFrame]->[super initWithFrame:CGRectZero], it will call subclass's initWithFrame then call super class's,that's make me confused? why call [YourClass initWithFrime:XX]?

Comment: I updated my answer, really what happens is that [super init] calls [self initWithFrame]...this is what triggers the [YourClass initwithFrame:] and then in turn calls [super initWithFrame:]

Comment: yeah, if it's then the answer should be. but why "[super init] calls [self initWithFrame]" as we know super is magic word tell compiler to find methods in super class, so should  "[super init] calls [super initWithFrame]" ???

Comment: That is how apple implemented it. The base implementation of [UIView init] calls [UIView initWithFrame:CGRectZero]. It is unclear to us why apple made this decision but it was likely to simplify their code and offer a convenience initializer for UIView. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: ok, finally i get it. thanks very much. the sequence after [super init] is [self initWithFrame:xx];

Answer (score 0):

> it will call call [super init] then it will call [super
>   initWithFrame:xx] as super will find methods in super class, why it
>   will call [myView initWithFrame:xx]???

No. There is no such thing is `super`. `super` is just a syntax to allow you to call a method on `self`, using a different method lookup mechanism. Here, the `[super init]` call will lookup to the method `-[UIView init]` which is called on your object (the one `self` points to). Inside `-[UIView init]`, it has a call `[self initWithFrame:]`, which again, is called on your object (the one `self` points to). Here it does not use `super`, so the normal method lookup mechanism is used (the superclass of `UIView` doesn't have `-initWithFrame:` anyway). The normal method lookup mechanism finds the most overridden implementation in the class of the object. Since your class (the class of your object) overrides `-initWithFrame:`, the method it looks up to is `-[YourClass initWithFrame:]`.

Comment: Thanks.  And i think i misunderstand the keyword super before the question. now i know it with you and john_ryan's help-->super is just a syntax to allow you to call a method on self, using a different method lookup mechanism.